# MS SQL - User Defined Function - Slope Intercept RSquare ; How to Group by Portfolio

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics, user-defined-functions

Below is an example of my data, table RR_Linest:

Portfolio   ----         Month_number      ----           Collections
A               ---       ---------      1    ---------------------                          $100-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A--------------                            2    ---------------------                        $90
A                         -------------   3       ---------------------                     $80--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A                    -------------        4      ---------------------                      $70--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B  -------------                          1    --------------------                        $100-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B            ----        --------        2     ----------------------                       $90  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B                  -      ------------    3                         ---------------------   $80

I was able to figure out how to how to get the slope,intercept, RSquare for one portfolio by removing the portfolio column and only selecting the month_Number (x) and collections data (y) for only **one selected portfolio** (I removed data for portfolio B) and running the code below.

**I have been trying to change the function so that when I run it; it gives me the slope, intercept, and R-square by portfolio.  Does someone know how to do that?  I have tried many ways and I just can't figure it out.**

**First I created the function:**

declare @RegressionInput_A  [dbo].[RegressionInput_A]

insert into @RegressionInput_A (x,y)
select
([model month]),log([collection $])
from [dbo].[RR_Linest]

select * from [dbo].LinearRegression_A

```
GO

drop function dbo.LinearRegression_A

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LinearRegression_A
( 
@RegressionInputs_A AS dbo.RegressionInput_A READONLY 
) 
RETURNS @RegressionOutput_A TABLE 
( 
Slope DECIMAL(18, 6), 
Intercept DECIMAL(18, 6), 
RSquare DECIMAL(18, 6) 
) 
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Xaverage AS DECIMAL(18, 6)
DECLARE @Yaverage AS DECIMAL(18, 6)
DECLARE @slope AS DECIMAL(18, 6)
DECLARE @intercept AS DECIMAL(18, 6)
DECLARE @rSquare AS DECIMAL(18, 6)

SELECT
@Xaverage = AVG(x),
@Yaverage = AVG(y)
FROM
@RegressionInputs_A

SELECT
@slope = SUM((x - @Xaverage) * (y - @Yaverage))/SUM(POWER(x - @Xaverage, 2))
FROM
@RegressionInputs_A

SELECT
@intercept = @Yaverage - (@slope * @Xaverage) 

SELECT @rSquare = 1 - (SUM(POWER(y - (@intercept + @slope * x), 2))/(SUM(POWER(y - (@intercept + @slope * x), 2)) + SUM(POWER(((@intercept + @slope * x) - @Yaverage), 2))))
FROM
@RegressionInputs_A

INSERT INTO
@RegressionOutput_A
(
Slope,
Intercept,
RSquare
)
SELECT
@slope,
@intercept,
@rSquare

RETURN

END
GO
```

**Then I run the function**

```
declare @RegressionInput_A  [dbo].[RegressionInput_A]

insert into @RegressionInput_A (x,y)
select
([model month]),log([collection $])
from [dbo].[RR_Linest]

select * from [dbo].[LinearRegression_A](@RegressionInput_A)
```

Comment: Did you check my solution.  Are the results as expected.  It has been a while since I did a LR by hand.  It could be reduced by using the STDEV() function.  By the solution shows the intermediate results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, this is a real cool example of how to use nested CTE's in a In Line Table Value Function.  You want to use a ITVF since they are fast.  See Wayne Sheffield’s [blog](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/) article that attests to this fact.

I always start with a sample database/table if it is really complicated to make sure I give the user a correct solution.

Lets create a database named [test] based on model.

```
--
-- Create a simple db
--

-- use master
use master;
go

-- delete existing databases
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'Test')
DROP DATABASE Test
GO

-- simple db based on model
create database Test;
go

-- switch to new db
use [Test];
go
```

Lets create a table type named [InputToLinearReg].

```
--
-- Create table type to pass data
--

-- Delete the existing table type
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.systypes WHERE name = 'InputToLinearReg')
DROP TYPE dbo.InputToLinearReg
GO

--  Create the table type
CREATE TYPE InputToLinearReg AS TABLE
(
portfolio_cd char(1),
month_num int,
collections_amt money
);
go
```

Okay, here is the multi-layered SELECT statement that uses CTE's.  The query analyzer treats this as a SQL statement which can be executed in parallel versus a regular function that can't.  See the black box section of Wayne's article.

```
--
-- Create in line table value function (fast)
--

-- Remove if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('CalculateLinearReg') > 0
DROP FUNCTION CalculateLinearReg
GO

-- Create the function
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateLinearReg
( 
    @ParmInTable AS dbo.InputToLinearReg READONLY 
) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(

  WITH cteRawData as
  (
    SELECT
        T.portfolio_cd,
        CAST(T.month_num as decimal(18, 6)) as x,
        LOG(CAST(T.collections_amt as decimal(18, 6))) as y
    FROM
        @ParmInTable as T
  ),

  cteAvgByPortfolio as
  (
    SELECT
        portfolio_cd,
        AVG(x) as xavg,
        AVG(y) as yavg
    FROM
        cteRawData 
    GROUP BY 
        portfolio_cd
  ),

  cteSlopeByPortfolio as
  (
    SELECT
        R.portfolio_cd,
        SUM((R.x - A.xavg) * (R.y - A.yavg)) / SUM(POWER(R.x - A.xavg, 2)) as slope
    FROM
        cteRawData as R 
    INNER JOIN 
        cteAvgByPortfolio A
    ON 
        R.portfolio_cd = A.portfolio_cd
    GROUP BY 
        R.portfolio_cd
  ),

  cteInterceptByPortfolio as
  (
    SELECT
        A.portfolio_cd,
        (A.yavg - (S.slope * A.xavg)) as intercept
    FROM
        cteAvgByPortfolio as A
    INNER JOIN 
        cteSlopeByPortfolio S
    ON 
        A.portfolio_cd = S.portfolio_cd

  )

  SELECT 
      A.portfolio_cd,
      A.xavg,
      A.yavg,
      S.slope,
      I.intercept,
      1 - (SUM(POWER(R.y - (I.intercept + S.slope * R.x), 2)) /
      (SUM(POWER(R.y - (I.intercept + S.slope * R.x), 2)) + 
      SUM(POWER(((I.intercept + S.slope * R.x) - A.yavg), 2)))) as rsquared
  FROM
      cteRawData as R 
        INNER JOIN 
      cteAvgByPortfolio as A ON R.portfolio_cd = A.portfolio_cd
        INNER JOIN 
      cteSlopeByPortfolio S ON A.portfolio_cd = S.portfolio_cd
        INNER JOIN 
      cteInterceptByPortfolio I ON S.portfolio_cd = I.portfolio_cd
  GROUP BY 
      A.portfolio_cd,
      A.xavg,
      A.yavg,
      S.slope,
      I.intercept
);
```

Last but not least, setup a Table Variable and get the answers.  Unlike you solution above, it groups by portfolio id.

```
-- Load data into variable
DECLARE @InTable AS InputToLinearReg;

-- insert data
insert into @InTable
values
('A', 1, 100.00),
('A', 2, 90.00),
('A', 3, 80.00),
('A', 4, 70.00),
('B', 1, 100.00),
('B', 2, 90.00),
('B', 3, 80.00);

-- show data
select * from CalculateLinearReg(@InTable)
go
```

Here is a picture of the results using your data.

[image]

Comment: Wow!! That is awesome, now that is some good work.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am glad you like it.  Please note that the LOG() function is inside the ITVF.  It can be in the dataset if need be.  Please give me the credit for the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LinearRegression 
( 
  @RegressionInputs AS dbo.RegressionInput READONLY 
) 
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
  WITH
    t1 AS ( --calculate averages
      SELECT portfolio, x, y,
        AVG(x) OVER(PARTITION BY portfolio) Xaverage,
        AVG(y) OVER(PARTITION BY portfolio) Yaverage
      FROM @RegressionInputs
    ),
    t2 AS ( --calculate slopes
      SELECT portfolio, Xaverage, Yaverage,
        SUM((x - Xaverage) * (y - Yaverage))/SUM(POWER(x - Xaverage, 2)) slope
      FROM t1
      GROUP BY portfolio, Xaverage, Yaverage
    ),
    t3 AS ( --calculate intercepts
      SELECT portfolio, slope,
        (Yaverage - (slope * Xaverage) ) AS intercept
      FROM t2
    ),
    t4 AS ( --calculate rSquare
      SELECT t1.portfolio, slope, intercept,
        1 - (SUM(POWER(y - (intercept + slope * x), 2))/(SUM(POWER(y - (intercept + slope * x), 2)) + SUM(POWER(((intercept + slope * x) - Yaverage), 2)))) AS rSquare
      FROM t1
      INNER JOIN t3 ON (t1.portfolio = t3.portfolio)
      GROUP BY t1.portfolio
    )
  SELECT portfolio, slope, intercept, rSquare FROM t4
)
```